# fancyBox Gallery

Tags: php, fancybox

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Firstly I apologise for what most may feel is a really simple question. But this is my first attempt so please bear with me.

I'm using the script below to create an Image Gallery with Fancybox.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
  <title>Gallery</title>  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.4.pack.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.2"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.0"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.6"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.2" type="text/css" media="screen" />  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />  

  <script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a.fancybox-thumb").fancybox({

        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });

});


</script>  

</head> 
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; font-size: 9px; border-bottom-width: thin; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 100px; margin-right: 100px; margin-bottom: -10px; float: left; position: absolute;"> 
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "javascript:document.gallery.submit()"/> Add Images <a/> &larr; View Uploaded Images </div> 
  <form id="gallery" name="gallery" class="page" action="index.php" method="post">   

                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) :  
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i);  
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source'));  
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail'));  
                  ?> 
        <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="allimages" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></a><?php endfor; ?> 
  </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

I can view the images, but I just can't seem to get the gallery functionality working. I've been working through the examples on the 'fancyBox' and 'fancyApps'websites, but clearly I've misunderstood something along the way.

I feel that once I get started I can format the page as I need it to look, I'll just working through the tutorials. But I just wondered if someone could perhaps please show me where I've gone wrong in creating the initial gallery.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: I would first make sure you're using the latest jQuery library.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> this is not the lastest

Comment: Both, many thanks for this. I've updated to the most recent version. Kind regards

Comment: I would try building the gallery without PHP to see if it's a structure error rather than a php script error. After looking over the code again, the only mistake I see is the one found by @kernelpanic.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for continuing to help me. I've done as you suggested, removing the php, but unfortunately the grey vertical line is still there. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the initial issues raised by @kernelpanic, @ryan and @Mr_DeLeTeD were rectified, through further testing and having looked through the documenation, the 'grey vertical stripe' was the opacity setting and not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I're attaching your fancybox to a class called ".fancybox-thumb", yet there is no such class on the page. Instead, your links bear class called ".images"

So try replacing this line

```
<a class="images" rel="allimages" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></a><?php endfor; ?>
```

with

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="allimages" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></a><?php endfor; ?>
```

I haven't tested your code but that's one obvious mistake I found so far.

Comment: Hi @kernelpanic. Many thanks for taking the time to help. I've made the chang, but unfortunately I'm still unable to produce the gallery. Kind regards

Comment: Do you know how to use the console window in the browser, such as Firebug for Firefox? Or there's one built in for Chrome. See if it give you any error when you're clicking on the thumbnail

Comment: Hi @kernelpanic. I've done a little more work and tested in my defualt browwer which is IE and Firefox and neither give any error message. I can now get the gallery to appear, but when I click on the image there is a grey square that appears vertically down the page. I include a link which may help a little better than my explanation http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testindex.php. Just select the 'View Uploaded Images' link at the top of the page I have updated the code in my original post. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Hi @kernelpanic, please see my answer below. Sincere thanks for all your time and trouble. Kind regards